# Hybride Mobile App (Phonegap) map offline and routing

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, web, maps

I'm currently developping a phonegap mobile application and I want to be able to add the functionnalities of a map.
The features I want in this map is :

- can be used offline
- can be used to routing the user from a point A to a point B
- performant solution
- Usable on Android 4 minimum
- Free solution

Do you know any solution that can be suitable for me? I have looked on internet but nothing is good as I want.
Thanks.